# how can i customize in Visual Studio the autocomplete color in the popup

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Either this is found in Tools Options Fonts and Colors, or it's something editable with Visual Studio Color Theme Designer 2022 (an extension from Microsoft DevLabs).

[image]

As you can see, the word `cast` is white on pale-blue, which is very hard to read (and impossible at smaller scale).  I have not been able to locate the setting that will adjust this.

Comment: please try from here [User-customizable colors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/ux-guidelines/colors-and-styling-for-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#user-customizable-colors) from MSDocs.

Comment: Having perused through that, gets me nowhere.  I can guess the Theme Designer uses this technology, but I don't see how I can figure out what element I need from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a process: the blue in the picture is #FFC4D5FF.  In the Theme editor, sorting by Color, I found about 50 items colored with this color.  Among those is it
Cider -> ListItemMouseOver?
SearchControl ->PopupControlMouseOverBackgroundGradientMiddle2?

I have no clue.  I changed all of them to #FF2362FF.  Apply/save, and go to my editor, and I get:

[image]

So one of the 50 items is the thing I needed to change.  Who knows what else changed.  The labels are all very obscure to me.  In the event something of these is trouble, I'll have to delve more deeply into the set of elements.

Comment: Glad to hear that you have resolved it.